# For each distinct value in col_a, yield a new table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have an Athena table of data in S3 that acts as a source table, with columns `id`, `name`, `event`. For every unique `name` value in this table, I would like to output a new table with all of the rows corresponding to that `name` value, and save to a different bucket in S3. This will result in n new files stored in S3, where n is also the number of unique `name` values in the source table.

I have tried single Athena queries in Lambda using `PARTITION BY` and CTAS queries, but can't seem to get the result that I wanted. It seems that AWS Glue may be able to get my expected result, but I've read online that it's more expensive, and that perhaps I may be able to get my expected result using Lambda.

**How can I store a new file (JSON format, preferably) that contains all rows corresponding to each unique `name` in S3?**

Preferably I would run this once a day to update the data stored by `name`, but the question above is the main concern for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When u write your spark/glue code you will need to partition the data using the name column. However this will result in a path having the below format

S3://bucketname/folder/name=value/file.json

This should give a separate set of files for each name value, but if u want to access that as a separate table u might need to get rid of that = sign from the key before u crawl the data and make it available via Athena

If u do use a lambda, the operation involves going through the data , similar to what glue does, and partitioning the data

I guess it all depends on the volume of data that it needs to process. Glue, if using spark may have a little bit of an extra start up time. Glue python shells have comparatively better start up times

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is essentially the same conclusion I've come to as well, though I'm partitioning from AWS Glue. My current issue is that in the original question, I stated that I wanted to partition by a `name` column, though in reality it's a `url` column. However, your reply answers my question completely!